# I have 2 transactions on electrum wallet still not confirmed

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, electrum

for 7 days now i have had 2 electrum transactions still not send next to both of them it says low fee is there any solution to make them send or cancel my transactions

Transaction ID 2: 7322490976f276b78c746d3208136d71fdfd35144170a591d63db3c68a8e93b4

Transaction ID 1:b48cdb255f29c6c2d7dfa0cc77f62be6dfb5e3443f910e0d9aa376010cd7486f

Comment: Does following this advice fix your problem? http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50064/how-to-unstuck-a-low-fee-transaction-with-electrum