# Transaction taking a long time to confirm, now it doesn't even show up on Bitcoin Explorer

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, unconfirmed-transactions, lost-bitcoins, lost-transactions

UPDATE: Electrum now says the transaction is "Local" and now I have an option to "broadcast", should I do that?

OP:

So, I'm trying to spend a small amount of bitcoin on a website (not relevant) and I send over 0.0010346 BTC with a fee of 0.0000543 BTC  ( 30.2 sat/byte ) and it's been almost 24 hours, and it still hasn't confirmed. The website stated it saw my payment, and will convert my BTC into balance once the BTC gets confirmed, and it's stressing me out because I'm afraid my BTC was lost somehow... I'm generally new to BTC so any help is appreciated.

The transaction used to show up on Bitcoin Explorer (blockstream.info) which is what my wallet (electrum) directs me do, and now it doesn't?!? Really stressing me. Transaction id is c4bea179e5e772b131c475f9030088b67dea5054a545713dc32458829fa61598

Comment: Hi Connor,
I think the main gist of your question is addressed on https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50064/how-to-unstuck-a-low-fee-transaction-with-electrum. Could you please check that topic out? A transaction at 30 sat/B is probably going to confirm sometime next week.

Answer (score 1):

I can see the transaction here: https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/c4bea179e5e772b131c475f9030088b67dea5054a545713dc32458829fa61598

This is how you can visualize your transaction in a [pool](https://mempool.observer/) of other unconfirmed transactions with different fee rates:

[image: mempool]

Miners prioritize transactions with higher fee rates from this pool to add in the blocks and thats how transactions are confirmed. Your transaction will stay lower in the pool and less likely to get confirmed until others keep using higher fee rate.

Also there is a limit of [300 MB](https://twitter.com/lopp/status/1321526650648043520) used by most of the full nodes which might result in lot of low fee rate transactions being dropped from their mempool. Not sure if this will affect your transaction with fee rate: 30 sat/vByte.

1. RBF was not enabled for this transaction. Ensure that you are using a wallet that [supports RBF](https://bitcoinops.org/en/compatibility/#replace-by-fee-rbf) and enable it for most of the transactions. It allows you to add more fees later.
2. CPFP cannot be done in this case as it has only one output which I am assuming owned by the website.
3. Be patient and wait for couple of days. Email the website support about this issue.

Comment: So as for an eta, it's almost certain that I have to wait a couple days?

Comment: I cannot predict things about mempool. Expecting things to settle by weekend. You can also use LN for bitcoin payments which works better if the website supports it. Here is a list of LN wallets: https://blog.bitrefill.com/top-11-lightning-network-wallets-bitrefill-328b5465b1b4

Comment: It now says status is local, and I have an option to broadcast, should I do it?

Comment: Yes rebroadcast it. Maybe it was dropped from mempool.

Comment: The MB to tip keeps increasing.. is that bad

Comment: Fee rate distribution: https://i.imgur.com/sU4Okpp.jpg 30 sat/vByte transactions should confirm by Monday

Comment: @Connor: A transaction with feerate of 30 sat/B will probably not confirm before next week. You can either increase the fee of your transaction or wait it out.