# How do I clear a stuck Bitcoin transaction.The other answers did not help my situation

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

How do I clear a stuck Bitcoin transaction without being in control of the senders wallet? 
I have a #number to go on and my wallet address.
The sender does not know how to help me.

Comment: related: [Replace-by-Fee vs Child-pays-for-Parent?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/49723/5406), see the "Child-pays-for-parent" part. ;)

Comment: Clear as in `settle` or clear as in `erase`?

Answer (score 1):

if the transaction did not use the optional replace-by-fee scheme, then after 14 days it should be dropped from all mempools and the sender would have the coins back.

if the sender is unavilable or uncooperative and you need the transaction to go through, look for miner priority services; they allow you to pay a fee to get the transaction prioritized.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the easiest option for super-technical users is to use Transaction Accelerators:

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_accelerator

> Transactions with too low a fee can take hours or even days to confirm, and sometimes never confirm at all.

Never done testing in real-life if they actually work / are reliable.

Much easier to set a correct fee - or allow software do this automatically.