# Unconfimed transaction

Tags: transactions

I have sent BTC to cryptopay wallet. It is still showing pending. It has been 8 hours up to now. Can you please tell me what could be the error or the problem and how I can solve the issue
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The fee specified by your send transaction could be too small for any miner to include it in a block of transactions.

Some -- possibly too much -- information about fees is here: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees

Answer (score 0):

First check a block explorer like blockchain.info to see if the transaction was even broadcast.  If it was not, then look into resetting your wallet.

If you see the tx on a public block explorer, then you probably underpaid fees - [See this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it).  Here are some options:

- If BTC was *sent* from Electrum (or another wallet that supports RBF), then add a larger fee.
- If you own the *destination* wallet, you can try using Child-Pays-For-Parent -- just send the unconfirmed amount to yourself with a very high fee.
- If neither of the above are true and you didn't use Bitcoin Core, you may have to just wait or find some other way to double spend your tx...

More info on ways to modify fees after tx is sent: [Replace-by-Fee vs Child-pays-for-Parent?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49723/replace-by-fee-vs-child-pays-for-parent)